# How can I copy the content of one google doc file to another google doc file using google doc api?

Tags: java, google-docs-api, google-api-java-client

I have a google doc file with some initial content and i want to append to it the content(all of the body part) of another google doc file. I am using the google docs api using java.

I can read contents from the google doc file which i want to copy as follows:

```
Document doc = service.documents().get(DOCUMENT_ID).execute();
doc.getBody().getContent()
```

But i do not know how to insert this content to my another google doc file. Specifically, in my case, I have a table in one of my google doc file. and I want to copy that table to my other google doc file. so, first, I am getting the table as follows:

```
List<StructuralElement> structuralElements = doc.getBody().getContent()
 for (StructuralElement element : elements) {
     if (element.getTable() != null) {
        // How can i copy this "element.getTable()" table to my another google doc file 
        }
      }
  }
```

currently I am using the following code to add contents using batchUpdate operation and requests:

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest();
service.documents().batchUpdate(DOCUMENT_ID, body.setRequests(requests)).execute();
```

I have looked at the google docs api documentation but i could not find what i am looking for.
Is there any approach or any recommendations to perform this operation?

N.B. I am aware that, in Google App Script, there is method to append table to a google doc file which is:

`body.appendTable(table)`

So, is there something like this in Java, which we can use to append a table from one doc file to another doc file.

Comment: You seem to want a very simple use of the API. Have you read the [guide](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text#inserting_text) mean to insert text? 
It even has a Java example of how to do it. Also please share your code so we know what have you tried and what error are you finding.

Comment: @Raserhin thank you for your comment. but, I have two separate google doc files(i want to copy the content of one of the doc files, to the other doc file). The above link you sent me only inserts texts in to google doc. in mycase, it is a whole body content(it can include text, tables ..). the link you provided me only inserts some text to a doc file.

Comment: Hello, is your question how to copy a table to a different doc? Depending on what you need to copy, you would have to use different methods. If your question is specifically related to tables, I'd consider posting an answer for this. If that's not the case, I'd suggest you to provide a copy of the document you are working on, it can help others to help you.